# How to create specfic clickable layout - android

Tags: android

I want to make such layout:

[image: layout]

Each item has own colored area. This area shows when the item is used. Each area must be clickable. On the right are shown weeks. On top are shown some items. This layout must be scrollable down and to the side. I dont have any idea how to make this.

Comment: do you have any experience with custom ViewGroup? creating a custom layout is a way you should follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set those areas with a binding, and give an ID to each binding. 
Then you will select an onclick event for each ID and binding with an action that you will define.

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ScrollView and TableLayout